# Divisibility of odd numbers and its sum of divisors function

Tags: divisibility, divisor-sum

Let us denote as $d(n)$ some proper divisor of $n$ such that $n$ is odd.

I found recently the following

**Theorem**

If $n=p^\alpha*q$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, and $q=p^\alpha-\frac{p^\alpha-1}{p-1}$, then $$\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{n}}d\left(n\right)\mid n$$

The proof relies on the fact that, as $p^\alpha>q$, then the sum of proper divisors of $n$ which are less than the square root of $n$ is $$\frac{p^\alpha-1}{p-1}+q=p^\alpha$$

I was wondering if

1. Could be this theorem biconditional? That is, could it be proved that $\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{n}}d\left(n\right)\mid n$ only if $n=p^\alpha*q$?
2. If answer to question 1 is negative (this theorem is not biconditional), could this theorem be true also for $n=p^\alpha*q^\beta$ such that $\beta>1$? How to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, 80 is not of your form, but matches the divisibility condition.

Comment: @IvanNeretin , $80$ is not odd, and $80=2^4*5$, so it is of the form $p^\alpha*q$

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Well, try 7605 then.

Comment: @IvanNeretin , thanks, it is a nice counterexample, as $7605=3^2*13^2*5$ That answers perfectly question 1.

Comment: I can generalize a little bit more, albeit _not_ in the direction suggested by your question 2. See, we can have $q=p^\alpha-\frac{p^\alpha-1}{p-1}$ like you said, but we can also use $q=p^\alpha\color{red}{\pmb+}\frac{p^\alpha-1}{p-1}$ (when this happens to be a prime, that is). Examples include $n=117,\;775,\;88723,\;796797$.

Comment: Well seen @IvanNeretin! I was wondering that, as your counterexample is of the form $m^\alpha*q$, $m$ being composite, if the theorem would be biconditional if we put it as "if and only if $n=m^\alpha*q$, with $q$ prime... what do you think?

Comment: I don't know where to move further, so I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: @JuanMoreno, your formula for $q$ is equal to
$$q = p^{\alpha} - \frac{p^{\alpha} - 1}{p - 1} = p^{\alpha} - \bigg(\sigma(p^{\alpha}) - p^{\alpha}\bigg) = 2p^{\alpha} - \sigma(p^{\alpha}) = D(p^{\alpha}),$$
where $D(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the positive integer $x$.

Comment: @JuanMoreno:  I have posted a follow-up to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3602902).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your formula for $q$ is equal to
$$q = p^{\alpha} - \frac{p^{\alpha} - 1}{p - 1} = p^{\alpha} - \bigg(\sigma(p^{\alpha}) - p^{\alpha}\bigg) = 2p^{\alpha} - \sigma(p^{\alpha}) = D(p^{\alpha}),$$
where $D(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the positive integer $x$, and $\sigma$ is the classical *sum-of-divisors* function.