# Divisibility of odd numbers and its sum of divisors function - Part II

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, solution-verification, divisor-sum

This question is inspired by this earlier one:

[Divisibility of odd numbers and its sum of divisors function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585453)

In that question, [MSE user Juan Moreno](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/567304) claims to have discovered a proof for the following "**Theorem**":

> "**Theorem**": Let us denote as $d(n)$ some proper divisor of $n$ such that $n$ is odd.  If $n=p^{\alpha} q$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, and $q=p^{\alpha}-\frac{p^{\alpha}-1}{p-1}$, then $$\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{n}}d\left(n\right)\mid n.$$

Of course, we obtain
$$q = p^{\alpha}-\frac{p^{\alpha}-1}{p-1} = p^{\alpha} - \bigg(\sigma(p^{\alpha}) - p^{\alpha}\bigg) = 2p^{\alpha} - \sigma(p^{\alpha}) = D(p^{\alpha}),$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the positive integer $x$.  (Here, $\sigma$ is the classical *sum-of-divisors* function.)

Since
$$D(p^{\alpha}) < p^{\alpha}$$
(for prime $p$ and $\alpha \geq 1$), and since
$$D(p^{\alpha}) + s(p^{\alpha}) = p^{\alpha},$$
where $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [sum of aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$, is Juan Moreno correct when he claimed that
$$\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{n}}d\left(n\right) = D(p^{\alpha}) + s(p^{\alpha}) = p^{\alpha}?$$